# Recaptcha using Netlify no validation?

Tags: recaptcha, netlify

I can successfully submit and send email by sending this kind of message. `name` , `email` and `comment`

and if the user submit it. Netlify will automatically send to my email the request from user.

However I tried to add recaptcha of netlify. It works fine. If submit the form by filling up all the necessary fields and checks the recaptcha it will send me an email. But if I didn't check the recaptcha it will just reset the page or reload the page. The question is how can I do validation if recaptcha is checked or not?

Here's my html

```
     <form id="my-form" name="contact" data-netlify="true" data-netlify-recaptcha="true" method="POST">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="ENTER YOUR NAME" required>
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="ENTER YOUR EMAIL" required>
            <br>
            <br>
            <textarea name="message" required></textarea>
            <br>
            <div data-netlify-recaptcha="true"></div>
            <br>
            <button type="submit" class="kingrg-submit"><span class="ion-android-send"></span>&nbsp;SUBSCRIBE</button>
            <br>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
           <div class="map kingrg-photo" style="z-index: 1;" id="map"></div>

        </div>
        </form>
```

Here's the output

[image]

and here's the email proof that it works only needs validation.

[image]